# storing intermediate data in storm topology

Tags: java, apache-storm, trident

I am reading data from 2 kafka topics. Which can be described as:

`Topic1 data content: VehicleRegistrationNo, Timestamp, Location
Topic2 data content: VehicleRegistrationNo, Timestamp, Speed`

I need to merge these 2 messages based on nearest timestamp in both and output tuple as message `VehicleRegistrationNo, Timestamp, Speed, Location`. I am reading these topic via 2 spouts `S1` and `S2`. Then bolt `MergeS1andS2` takes input from these spouts and works as:

`if (message from S1):
      save present message from S1 along with 2 previous messages (3 consecutive locations) to LocationHashMap
elseif (message from S2):
      get locations details from LocationHashmap and merge speed for same Vehicle with location info, then send details to next bolt as tuple`

I know HashMap is not efficient way of storing data in multinode. So I read about Trident and Redis to store intermediate data. What should I use to store my intermediate data in this senario which can work in distributed topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any no-sql database will do the trick. Pick a key that uniquely identifies the tuple regardless from which topic is coming from. The logic would be something like:

- Try to lookup the tuple from the database.
- If tuple does not exist in database, store the tuple that you got from the topic into the database.
- If tuple exists, merge contents of database tuple and topic tuple and store the resulting tuple back into the database (overwriting the contents of the previous tuple in the database)